# "Offers in app purchases" not showing in playstore

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I added In App Billing (Play Billing Library) in my android app. The manifest.xml contains `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` and I also added `compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'` in `build.gradle` file.
Through the Google Play Console, I created purchase item but on the Google Play app page, there is nothing about "Offers in app purchase".

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT**

"Offers in app purchase" appears on mobile but not on the web

It is in French but if I take this app :

[image]

Just above Install button there is "Contient des annonces - Contain ads" and "Achat via l'application proposés - Offers in app purchases".

For my app (in alpha release) I have:

[image]

Comment: Did you check in your developer console under `Console` -> `Store Presence` -> `In-App Products` if everything shows properly?

Comment: Yes everything is well defined

Comment: When you say it appears on mobile but not web, does it appear in other apps on the web?

Comment: I edited my question with screenshot